# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SETEX')

Tags: javascript, typescript, redis, typeerror, node-redis

***The error says Redis method "SETEX" undefined***
*and application deployed into Heroku cloud*

Here is the Node-Redis setup code, please Have a look

```js
import { createClient } from 'redis';
import { REDIS_URI } from '../config';

export let redisClient;

(async () => {
    try {
        redisClient = createClient({ url: REDIS_URI });
        // redisClient.on("connect", () => { 
        // })
        redisClient.on("error", (err) => console.log("Redis Client Connection Error"));

        console.log("Redis cashe app database connected...");
        await redisClient.connect();
        // if (NODE_ENV) {
        // } else {
        //     redisClient = createClient({
        //         url: REDIS_URI});
        //     redisClient.on("error", (err) => console.log("Redis Client Connection Error", err));

        //     console.log("Redis cashe app database connected...");
        //     await redisClient.connect();
        // }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Redis app connection Error...', error);
    }
})();
```

> Whenever I need redis to get or set the data I just called "redisClient" as a redis instance because it's an exported(I'm using ES6) instance of redis.

Here is the Full error

```js
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099027+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/dist/controller/contact/index.js:212
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099044+00:00 app[web.1]:                         return _redisClient.redisClient.SETEX(key, _config.REDIS_DEF_EXP_TIME, JSON.stringify(contacts));
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099045+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                         ^
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099045+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099046+00:00 app[web.1]: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SETEX')
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099046+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _callee5$ (/app/dist/controller/contact/index.js:212:57)
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099046+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryCatch (/app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:63:40)
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099047+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:294:22)
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099047+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Generator.next (/app/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:119:21)
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099048+00:00 app[web.1]:     at asyncGeneratorStep (/app/dist/controller/contact/index.js:22:103)
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099048+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _next (/app/dist/controller/contact/index.js:24:194)
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099048+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/dist/controller/contact/index.js:24:364
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099048+00:00 app[web.1]:     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099049+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/dist/controller/contact/index.js:24:97
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099049+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/dist/controller/contact/index.js:226:30
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099049+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:5074:18
2022-09-14T14:59:46.099050+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
 -->
```

And this is the OS Node environment setup

```js
**Environment:**
 - **Node.js Version**: 16.x
 - **Redis Server Version**: <!-- e.g. "redis-server --version" -->
 - **Node Redis Version**: 4.0.2
 -  - **Platform**:  Heroku Cloud OS
```

I'm getting the "SETEX" method undefined error, and the system isn't working anymore.

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't say that the Redis method `SETEX` is undefined, it says that it cannot read the property `SETEX` of an undefined value, i.e. the Redis client itself is undefined. This is probably because you do not await the creation of the client before using it.

Comment: I just copy the code whatever has in node-redis docs: https://github.com/redis/node-redis

Comment: Yes but you do it before you finished asynchronously initializing the client...

Answer (score 1):

Hey Internazionaleauto!

I suspect this is happening because of how you are exporting the Redis client.
If you change your initialization code to something like the following:

```
async function initRedisClient() {
    try {
        const client = createClient({ url: REDIS_URI });
        client.on("error", (err) => console.log("Redis Client Connection Error"));
        await client.connect();
        console.log("Redis cashe app database connected...");
        return client;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Redis app connection Error...', error);
    }
}

export { initRedisClient };
```

which you would now initialize in another file like so:

```
import { initRedisClient } from './initRedisClient'

// later in the file, in an async function body

const redisClient = await initRedisClient();
```

I suspect the original error should be fixed.

> The error says Redis method "SETEX" undefined and application deployed into Heroku cloud

This is because the code importing your original `export let redisClient;` does not wait for it to finish initializing, which means that it imports `redisClient` while it's still `undefined` and then tries to call methods on it.

Comment: It's not necessary to have the init function return the client, it can simply set `redisClient` as it does now (import bindings are live!). This has the benefit that other files can still simply import `redisClient` and as long as they don't use it before it was set, it will be fine (e.g. it's not a problem if it's used in other functions which are called later on).

Comment: About your last sentence: The problem is not _importing_ `redisClient` while it's still `undefined`, the problem is _using_ it too early. Its value will change afterwards (even if it was imported before), as import bindings are live. (If you have `export let a; export function setA () { a = 123 }` and then `import { a, setA } from './module.js'; console.log(a); setA(); console.log(a)` then you will get `undefined` followed by `123`.)

Comment: By the way, `export initRedisClient` is invalid syntax, it would have to be `export { initRedisClient }` (or you could prefix the function declaration with `export` instead).

Comment: @Trevor Atlas Thanks, Let me try like as you said.

Answer (score 0):

I solve problem

```
const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    socket:{
        host:process.env.REDIS_HOST,
        port:process.env.REDIS_PORT,
        tls:true,

    },
    password:process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,

})

This section is saved me
tls : true
```